# MeteorJS and Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, meteor

I had /clients/client.js , /server/server.js and /model.js

In model.js I had: "Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");
In client/server I had used this collection. All works fine.

After adding coffeescript. I had convert all my js (3) files into .coffee. Remove js files
and start meteor. But now I've got:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Lists is not defined

Why? Where is mistake?

Lists = new Meteor.Collection "lists"

Thanks

Comment: This is just a guess, but in the JavaScript version were you missing the `var` on purpose? If not, CoffeeScript will put that in automatically, as well as wrapping the scope, so what used to be a global will not be anymore.

Comment: Yes @phenomnomnominal should be right you need to use an `@` in front of your variables in coffeescript if you want to access them from other files

Comment: Not quite sure what @Akshat is on about, @ adds `this.` in front of a variable. If you want to make a variable global, you would typically do something like `root = this ? exports` and then `root.Lists = Lists`.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal `@` globalizes the variable. By using `this.`/`@` the variable is accessible in other files similar to how removing var works. On the server `this` is the `global` namespace and on the client its the `window` namespace

Comment: @Akshat, what about `(-> alert @).call foo: 'bar'`. Here `@` refers to the object that is passed into the function as the context. You can't assume that @ will be the global scope.

Comment: Its meant to be used in front of variable/function, in that example no variable is passed. More info at the meteor docs under coffeescript. http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript

Comment: @Lists = new Meteor.Collection "lists"

Comment: @Akshat, `this` is a JavaScript concept, `@` is just a CoffeeScript shorthand for it. `this` defines the context that a function is called under. In my example above, using `.call`, the first argument that is passed into the `.call` becomes `this` in the called function. Unless Meteor does something funky that changes CoffeeScript and JavaScript syntax, you cannot just make the blanket statement that `@` will always be the global object.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal I see what you mean, using `@` is the recommended way in the meteor docs & the discussions in meteor when scoping was introduced on IRC and the google group hence why I mentioned it. Of course it does not always guarantee the globalized scope, but in the context of this question it solves the issue via: `@Lists = new Meteor.Collection "lists"`

Answer (score 12):

See http://docs.meteor.com/#coffeescript about how to use `@` as a convenient way to define global variables from CoffeeScript inside of the Meteor environment.  As @Akshat mentioned in the comments, Meteor sets `this` at the top level to the global environment to make this easy.

Comment: Is this still the recommended method? I noticed the documentation at the link provided doesn't mention using `@` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

With coffeescript, if you want to access your variable/function in another file, you need to expose your variable

From the meteor docs

> Global variables can be set in CoffeeScript by using this (or CoffeeScript's @ shorthand), because at the top level this refers to the global namespace (window on the client and global on the server). Thus
>
> @myFunction = -> 123
> at the top level sets the global variable myFunction.

So globalize your list:

```
@Lists = new Meteor.Collection "lists";
```

So that this inside `model.js` can be accessed by your other files (it becomes global)